# EMMS + Mplayer: stop cover showing up when playing music

Tags: osx, emms

I've been using EMMS with mplayer for a couple days, and a minimal config:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
(require 'emms-setup)
(require 'emms-player-mplayer)      ; load mplayer
(emms-all)
(emms-default-players)
(setq emms-source-file-default-directory "/Users/me/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/")
(emms-add-directory-tree emms-source-file-default-directory)
```

It worked very well, `M-x emms` would generate a buffer with the name of all files, and hitting `RET` would play it. However, for some reason, whenever I `RET` to play a song, an mplayer window pops up with the album cover, and when a songs end, this window pops up again showing the album cover for the next song. How can I remove this behavior and make emms as "silent" as possible? The album covers are embedded in the audio files.

Question: how to stop this popup window with the album cover?

Comment: Why do you use `(emms-all)` and not e.g., `(emms-minimalistic)` or just write your own config with the information from [emms-setup.el](https://github.com/emacsmirror/emms/blob/master/lisp/emms-setup.el).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I wasn't aware of all those options! I found out that I can set mplayer options to be quite, and it seems to work `(setq  emms-player-mplayer-parameters '("-slave" "-quiet"))`

Comment: If those options work for you please answer your own question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my emacs26.2 use

```
(append emms-player-mplayer-parameters (list "-novideo"))
```

worked for me, however I think it's may disable the videoplay function.

Comment: after update, this answer no function and I use  '(emms-player-mplayer-parameters (quote ("-slave" "-quiet" "-really-quiet" "-novideo"))) (first quote is essential)

Answer (score 0):

Following setting works for me in Mac with mplayer installed in **/usr/local/bin**

```
(use-package emms
:ensure t
:config
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))

(emms-standard)
(emms-default-players)
(setq  emms-player-mplayer-parameters '("-novideo"))
)
```